# ArcPy: Feature class "doesn't exist" after MakeFeatureLayer

Tags: arcpy

I was working on a Python script to analyze the geometries of a feature class and write something out. It worked fine the first time, but gave an IOError each subsequent time. I narrowed the problem down to the following: (not my actual code, but shows the weird behavior)

```
arcpy.Exists("MyFeatureClass")  # returns true
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management("MyFeatureClass", "MyFeatureLayer")
arcpy.Delete_management("MyFeatureLayer")  # returns true
arcpy.Exists("MyFeatureClass")  # returns FALSE
```

Can anyone think of why the feature class would become inaccessible after making a feature layer out of it? Something to do with locks?

Comment: From the comments below, this might be a case to post your actual, relevant code (if possible) in case it's a specific error in it. Did you try the exact same thing as Blah238 tried from the command prompt? What about a brand new script?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Works fine here:

```py
>>> fc = r"C:\GISData\atlantic_hurricanes_2000.shp"
>>> lyr = arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(fc)
>>> lyr
<Result 'atlantic_hurricanes_2000_Lay'>
>>> lyr.getOutput(0)
<map layer u'atlantic_hurricanes_2000_Lay'>
>>> lyr = lyr.getOutput(0)
>>> lyr.name
u'atlantic_hurricanes_2000_Lay'
>>> arcpy.Exists(fc)
True
>>> arcpy.Exists(lyr)
True
>>> arcpy.Exists(lyr.name)
True
>>> arcpy.Delete_management(lyr)
<Result 'true'>
>>> arcpy.Exists(lyr.name)
False
>>> arcpy.Exists(fc)
True
```

Works fine with a point feature class in a file geodatabase as well:

```py
>>> fc = r"C:\GISData\test.gdb\atlantic_hurricanes_2000"
>>> lyr = arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(fc).getOutput(0)
>>> arcpy.Exists(fc)
True
>>> arcpy.Delete_management(lyr)
<Result 'true'>
>>> arcpy.Exists(fc)
True
```

Comment: Thanks blah - I tried this again on a fresh GDB and you're right, it works fine. Must be something in my original dataset.

Comment: Actually... it only seems to work with polygon feature classes. Any new point classes I make have the same problem.

Comment: Works fine on a file geodatabase point feature class for me as well.

Comment: No matter how many new GDBs and MXDs I made, I could not get this work. But on another computer it was fine. Must be that copy of ArcGIS.